# Maven Java project in eclipse and mongodb libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, mongodb, maven

I have a Maven project in Java. I am new to all of these concepts. I created a Restful project which works well with a file repository. But I want to change that to a mongo repository.

So I added my repository class, then I need to add the mongo libraries. I right click on the project and select Maven --> Update, but the libraries are not being downloaded. So I add them myself via Project Build path and this makes my project to compile.

However at runtime I get the exception of classNotFound for mongo classes.

I read some posts and added these line to pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Still not compiling. How should I add the libraries in a way that it compiles and also at runtime my program can find those classes?

Comment: What error do you get?  You're missing the closing tag.

Comment: @tieTYT The tag was not missing it was just being interpreted as HTML as the block was not fully indented. But what errors are being received is relevant. As is making sure that this block is correctly nested inside a `<dependencies>` block in the POM. Noting the new initiate here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you get 1.3 for a version?  The latest is 2.12.1.

Comment: Thank you, what a stupid mistake. However I think Maven is to add these dependencies by itself, what is the use of Maven if I need to add them myself?

Comment: You want maven to know to automatically add mongo-java-driver?  That's not how maven (or any other build tool) works.

Comment: Then I think I need to study more about it. Thank you for clarification.